# Development SMTP Server

Tags: email, cross-platform, smtp

I need a cross platform (at least windows and mac) development utility that runs as an SMTP server that acts as an SMTP server but will redirect all mail to a single address that's configurable.  It would also be helpful if it wrote the contents out to a file or gui. Long ago I configured [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) to do this but it wasn't that straight forward to figure out.  Hoping there's something really simple out there.

I need the emails to be forwarded (to the single address) so I can see how they are rendered on different clients (gmail, outlook, etc.)

Thanks! -Mike

Comment: I have configured an IIS smtp service to act in this manner, but as you mentioned it wasn't the easiest to convince IIS to act in this way.

Answer (score 4):

We used [Mailtrap](http://mailtrap.io) for this. It give you remote smtp server account and direct access to all mails in it. So you just enter given smtp credential in your application and after that all email sent by your system will be visible on mailtrap.

On mailtrap you can have as many smtp account as you want( different account for different application environments, or different application) Also you can manage access to your account ( so only trusted people will se your emails) and you can forward some emails to real email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do the forwarding you are looking for, but for most of my testing I make use of fakemail (http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php) it's simply a script that listens on a port an acts as an smtp server, writing any incoming mail to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python's [`smtpd`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html) library and override the `process_message` function to only send to the desired address -- i.e. replace the "to" field with your desired constant email address.

[Here's a page with some examples](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/smtpd/) of using smtpd (with `asyncore`) to actually send out mail.